# Webkit background image is clipped

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a funny little problem.

I have a background image on my `body` element, and it loads like this in Webkit browsers (Chrome specifically).

[image: Bad!]

Resizing the window seems to fix this...

here is how it should look as intended:

[image: Good!]

CSS:

```
body {
padding-top: 360px;
font-family:Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;

background: url('images/page-bg2.jpg') no-repeat left center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

live site: http://www.healthfair.biz/

thanks guys!

Comment: Works for me in chrome (19.0.1084.56 m)

Comment: Works for me in chrome (21.0.1180.83 m) as well.

Comment: Works for me in chrome (21.0.1180.79 m) as well.  Background is slow loading however... maybe load it before displaying the page?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe the problem lies elsewhere. Thanks for checking for me!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to remove body padding-top (set th, and instead, use the same padding-top on div.wrapper. 
This should help.

Comment: Thanks - I'm never really sure what the best way to do these sorts of things is. It makes sense that you keep the properties responsible for the positioning and display of elements in the CSS of those elements